# How can I construct a nonmeasurable function $f$ such that $f^{-1}(a)$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f^{-1}(a)$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Is $f$ a measurable function ?

I think the answer is no, but I don't know how to give a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.  Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if }x\in A, \\  -x & \text{if }x\not\in A. \end{cases}
$$
The inverse-image of any single point under this function is measurable, but the inverse image of $[0,1]$ is the union of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and a non-measurable subset of $[-1,0]$.  If that union were measurable, then its intersections with $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ would be measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Any bijection $f:\mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$ has the property that $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is measurable for each  $a\in \mathbb {R}.$